Migrating aws amplify from v5 to v6
So i used to have aws amplify using version 5. now ive been asked to convert it to v6. the issue im facing is that v6 does not have Auth or API anymore in aws-amplify libraries. Can anyone help me with what i need to change in my file below
import { Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';

const makeRequest = async ({
    api = 'node-app',
    route,
    method = 'get',
    _options = {},
    _headers = {},
    responseType,
} = {}) => {
    const jwt = await Auth.currentSession();
    const { jwtToken } = jwt.idToken;
    const options = {
        ..._options,
        ...{ headers: { Authorization: jwtToken, ..._headers }, responseType },
    };
    return API[method](api, route, options);
};

export default makeRequest;

also the app was in js now its using typescript.
i know that the this const jwt = await Auth.currentSession(); can be get in v6 using const { idToken } = await cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.authTokenStore.loadTokens();
what other changes will i be required.
i have done the rest. this is just a helper function to call API

import { cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider } from 'aws-amplify/auth/cognito';
import { get, post, put, del } from 'aws-amplify/api';

interface MakeRequestParams {
    api?: string;
    route: string;
    method?: 'get' | 'post' | 'put' | 'delete' | 'patch';
    _options?: Record<string, unknown>;
    _headers?: Record<string, string>;
    responseType?: string;
}

const makeRequest = async ({
    route,
    method = 'get',
    _options = {},
    _headers = {},
    responseType,
}: MakeRequestParams): Promise<unknown> => {
    const { accessToken } = await cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.authTokenStore.loadTokens();

    const jwtToken = accessToken.toString();

    const options = {
        apiName: 'your api name',
        options: {
            headers: {
                Authorization: jwtToken,
                ..._headers,
            },
            ..._options,
        },
        path: route,
        responseType,
    };

    switch (method) {
        case 'get':
            return get(options);
        case 'post':
            return post(options);
        case 'put':
            return put(options);
        case 'delete':
            return del(options);
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid method');
    }
};
export default makeRequest;

